# Is there a way to gitignore a specific word?

Tags: git, vim, gitignore, fold

I want my git to ignore the vim-foldmarker ({{{,}}}) that I add to a repo.
I know git has the --ignore-whitespace option but,
is there a way to tell git to ignore a specific word or strings?
Of course I want git to track the diffs which is not "{{{" or "}}}"

if the original code cloned is

```python
def foo(bar):
    # do someting
    return "buz"
```

and I edit like

```python
def foo(bar): # {{{ <- this tells vim to fold from here
    # do something
    return "baz" # }}} to here
```

I want git diff to be like this

```
-    # do someting
+    # do something
-    return "buz"
*    return "baz"
```

not like this

```
-def foo(bar):
+def foo(bar): # {{{ <- this tells vim to fold from here
-    return "buz"
*    return "baz" # }}} to here
```

Comment: gitignore is for files and directories, not content - you can't do what you want with a gitignore file

Answer (score 2):

Git doesn't allow you to use a `.gitignore` file to ignore part of a file. You can either ignore the whole thing, or not ignore it at all.

However, there is a way to do what you want, which is a diff filter. If you edit the `.git/info/attributes` file (creating it if it doesn't exist), you can enter a line that says `*.py diff=vim`, which will make all Python files use the "vim" diff filter. You could also write this in `.gitattributes`, if you're the only person on the project, or in any other valid gitattributes file (see the man page for details).

Once you've done that, you can specify a diff filter in your `.git/config` file, or in your personal `.gitconfig` file. that specifies how to modify the file to render diffs. For example, you could write something like this:

```
[diff "vim"]
    textconv = "sed -e 's/ # {{{.*$//' -e 's/ # }}}.*$//'"
```

That will have `sed` modify all your diffs to strip out the whitespace, comments, and fold markers. You can perform arbitrary transformations on your files to modify them as you please for diff output.